# Toggle function not working

Tags: javascript, toggle, jquery, slidetoggle

Following is the code i was using for toggle.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

It works fine in my computer. But when I use it in the server side, which calls to .asp pages, it does not work. I know I have to use .live() handler. I tried it with the jquery slidetoggle. but it is not working. The following is the html code

```
<div class="issue_button">
<a align="center" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('dropdown1');">Link</a></div>
<div id="dropdown1"> <p>Some text</p> </div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Frankly I don't know how to write the code with live handler.

Comment: The style won't be present on the element if it's implicit.

Comment: Try adding a `return false;` at the end of your function otherwise clicking on the `<a>` will refresh the page and the `<div id="dropdown1">` will revert to its initial state, which I assume is _hidden_.

Comment: Where do you use jQuery's `.live()` handler? Also, if you have jQuery, why don't you use `.toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the jquery solution for toggle.

```
    <div class="issue_button">
        <a align="center" href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown1"> <p>Some text</p> </div>

$(function () {
    $(".issue_button a").click(function () {
        $("#dropdown1").slideToggle();
    });        
});​
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/aJFSy/1/

**Update**

I would not use Live since its deprecated since 1.7

Delegate - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
http://jsfiddle.net/aJFSy/2/

or

On
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4):

Since you said you can use jQuery, I suggest you this alternative code

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

try:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) { 
  var e = document.getElementById(id); 
  if(e.style.display == 'block'){
    e.style.display = 'none'; 
  }else{ 
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [learn how to format in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The braces will make absolutely no difference